# How to create an array of UIImages

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiimage

I'm storing an image from a Parse database like this:

```
PFFile *firstImageFile = self.product[@"firstThumbnailFile"];
[firstImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.firstImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
}];
```

I want to save the images as an array to display them inside a scrollview.

It works if I do something like this:

```
self.galleryImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"s2.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"s1.jpg"], nil];
```

But if I try to use the UIImage itself, no image appears.

```
self.galleryImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.firstImage, self.secondImage, nil];
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `self.firstImage` and `self.secondImage` are non-nil at the time you try to create the array?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it. How can I make sure is not nil? @rmaddy

Comment: Look at the value in the debugger or log it just before creating the array.

Comment: It's not, most likely because of `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock`. How can I set up my code so that it first saves the PFFile and then assigns it to the array? @rmaddy

Comment: Your last comment is confusing. Is `self.firstImage` nil or not at the time you create the array? You say its not but then the rest of the comment sort of implies that it is `nil`.

Comment: Sorry, it is nil at the time I'm creating the array. @rmaddy

Comment: Populate the array after you actually assign `self.firstImage` and `self.secondImage` (inside the completion blocks).

Answer (score 1):

This is form of a common problem:  how to do many asynch operations (without deeply nesting completion blocks) and know when they complete.  The approach I use is to think of the parameters to the operations as a todo list, and build a method that handles the list recursively....

```
- (void)loadPFFiles:(NSArray *)array filling:(NSMutableDictonary *)results completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {
    NSInteger count = array.count;
    // degenerate case is an empty array which means we're done
    if (!count) return completion(YES);

    // otherwise, do the first operation on the to do list, then do the remainder
    PFFile *file = array[0];
    NSArray *remainder = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, count-1)];

    [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            results[file.name] = image;
            [self loadPFFiles:remainder filling:results completion:completion];
        } else {
            completion(NO);
        }
    }];
}
```

Call it like this (guessing about your model a little bit):

```
NSArray *pfFiles = @[ self.product[@"firstThumbnailFile"], self.product[@"secondThumbnailFile"] ];
NSMutableDictionary *result = [@{} mutableCopy];

[self loadPFFiles:pfFiles filling:result completion:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        // result will be an dictionary of the loaded images
        // indexed by the file names
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess (based on your comments about nil above) that your code looks a little like this:

```
PFFile *firstImageFile = self.product[@"firstThumbnailFile"];
[firstImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.firstImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
}];

self.galleryImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.firstImage, self.secondImage, nil];
```

If this is the case, move the array initialization inside the completion block like so:

```
PFFile *firstImageFile = self.product[@"firstThumbnailFile"];
[firstImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.firstImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                self.galleryImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.firstImage, self.secondImage, nil];
            });
    }
}];
```

What happens in the first (your) case is that the array initialization statement runs before the completion block, so when 'first image' is actually set it is too late as the array has already been initialized.

Comment: I think you've got the right idea, but there's no need to dispatch to the main in the completion block... it will run on the main without that.  More importantly, `self.secondImage` assuming it's in the same state as the first image, will also be nil.  It too, must be loaded.  A common approach is nesting the second load within the first load's completion block, which is fine for a small, fixed number of operations.  I suggest a more general approach.