# Updating UI after multiple asynchronous completion handlers complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to make 12 requests to the same API (the data changes). Every time I make a request, I want to add the retrieved data to my array. The way I know how to do this is known as callback hell. It looks like this

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]    

  [self getRequestonPage:1 completion:^(BOOL succeeded, int data) {
                 [dataArray addObject:data];
  [self getRequestonPage:2 completion:^(BOOL succeeded, int data) {
                [dataArray addObject:data];
       [self getRequestonPage:3 completion:^(BOOL succeeded, int data) {
              [dataArray addObject:data];
    }];
  }];
}];
```

......etc, etc.  with 12 nested async completion handlers.

Once all the requests have been made, I want to update my UI with the data in my array. There has got to be a prettier way to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not separate getRequest: [self getRequest completion:^(BOOL succeeded, int data) {
                 [dataArray addObject:data];}];
  [self getRequest completion:^(BOOL succeeded, int data) {
                [dataArray addObject:data];}];

Comment: I see this question often, and answer it with different incarnations of this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897706/how-to-create-an-array-of-uiimages/31898423#31898423.  Let me know if that's specific enough to your situation.  If not, I can customize.

Comment: @anhtu, the OP hopes to know when all of the requests are complete.

Comment: why not use while + count var, or for loop?

Comment: @danh not specific enough, can you please customize it?

Comment: Are the requests all the same, the way you have in your question?

Comment: there is a page-counter. i need to get data from the pages 1-12. i've updated the question to show it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do an arbitrary number asynch requests and know when they complete:

(1) Represent the requests with something that parameterizes them.  In your case the requests are represented by page numbers.

```
NSArray *pages = @[ @1, @2, @3 /* ... */ ];
```

(2) Represent the results with a dictionary that associates the request parameter with the result of the asynch operation:

```
NSMutableDictionary *results = [@{} mutableCopy];
```

(3) A recursive algorithm to do a list of things goes like this: if the list is empty we're done, otherwise, do the first thing on the list, then do the rest of the list.  In code, you would call:

```
[self getPages:pages filling:results completion:^(BOOL success) {
    // here, we can update our UI
    // collecting the results in a dictionary allows us to know
    // which result goes with which request
}];

- (void)getPages:(NSArray *)pages filling:(NSMutableDictonary *)results completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {
    NSInteger count = pages.count;
    // degenerate case is an empty array which means we're done
    if (!count) return completion(YES);

    // otherwise, do the first operation on the to do list, then do the remainder
    NSNumber *page = pages[0];
    NSArray *remainder = [pages subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, count-1)];

    [self getRequest:[page intValue] completion:^(BOOL *success, int data) {
        if (success) {
            results[page] = @(data);
            [self getPages:remainder filling:results completion:completion];
        } else {
            completion(NO);
        }
    }];
}
```

Notice, in order to use the NS collections, we "wrap" page number `int`s and the returned `int`s as `NSNumber`.  But results will look like:

```
@{ @1 : @42, @2 : @154, etc...
```

Where @42 and @154 are NSNumber wrapped ints returned by your getRequest completion block.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)getAllPages {
    NSMutableArray * dataArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [self getPage:1 dataArray:dataArray];
}

-(void)getPage:(NSUInteger)page dataArray:(NSMutableArray *)dataArray {
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    [self getRequestonPage:page completion:^(BOOL succeeded, int data) {
         if (!succeeded) {
             [weakSelf handleErrorsSomehow];
             return;
         }
         [dataArray addObject:data];
         if (page < 12) {
             [weakSelf getPage:(page + 1) dataArray:dataArray];
         }
         else {
             // Update UI with dataArray.
         }
     }];
}
```